# in a php class, is there an easy way of defining variables with a function?

Tags: php, class, variables

in my class i have an array defined like this

```
class t {
    var $settings = array();
}
```

I will have these settings used quite a lot, so instead of writing `$this->settings['setting']` all over the place I wanted to deploy a function that automatically defines these settings in local variables.

```
private function get_settings () {

            $array = $this->settings['array'];
            $foreign_key = $this->settings['foreign_key'];
            $limit = $this->settings['limit'];
            $tableclassid = $this->settings['tableclassid'];
            $pager = $this->settings['pager'];
            $container = $this->settings['container'];
            $extracolumn = $this->settings['extracolumn'];
    }
```

now, what I want to do is to get these variables and use them in another function within class. In example

```
public function test () {
     $this->get_settings();
     return $foreign_key;
}
```

and I want it to return `$this->settings['foreign_key']`

is there a way to do this? Or do I have to clutter all the functions with that block of code get_settings() has?

I appreciate the help.. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built-in [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function, which extracts an array into individual variables in the current scope.

```
extract($this->settings);
```

If you need modifications to these local variables to be reflected in the original array, extract them as references.

```
extract($this->settings, EXTR_REFS);
```

I can't say I would prefer to use this method myself though, or even recommend that you do it. Inside of a class, it is much more readable and understandable to keep them in the array property.  In general, I never actually use `extract()`.

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to litter your variable namespace, even if you're in control of what's being extracted.

Comment: This works of course perfectly as the OP wants (+1 for that), but I would like to comment on this: `extract` in bigger codebases makes it a lot harder to see where variables are instantiated / coming from, so in my _personal_ opinion I would only use this sparingly.

Comment: @MarcB Couldn't agree more, and I added a note to that effect into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it as a property. Something like this:

```
$class = new T();
```

And then:

```
$class->getSettings('varname');
```

And in function:

```
function get_settings($varname){
    return $this->settings[$varname];
}
```

Or use the `__get()` overload function:

public function __get($name){
    return $this->settings[$name];
}

And call it like this:

$class->varname;

(non existing function/variable in class, will be sent to the get() overload function

Answer (score 1):

You can always overload the magic functions:

```
<?php

class DynamicSettings
{
    /**
     * Stores the settings
     * @var array
     **/
    protected $settings = array();

    /**
     * Called when something like this: 
     *  $dynset->name = value;
     * is executed.
     **/
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->settings[$name] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Called when something like this: 
     *  $value = $dynset->name;
     * is executed.
     **/
    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->settings)) 
        {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }
        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        trigger_error('Undefined dynamic property ' . $name .
            ' in ' . $trace[0]['file'] .
            ' on line ' . $trace[0]['line'],
            E_USER_NOTICE);
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Called when checking for variable existance
     **/
    public function __isset($name)
    {
        return isset($this->settings[$name]);
    }

    /**
     * Called when unsetting some value.
     **/
    public function __unset($name)
    {
        unset($this->settings[$name]);
    }

}

$dynset = new DynamicSettings();
$dynset->hello = "Hello "; // creates array key "hello" with value "Hello "
$dynset->world = "World!"; // creates array key "world" with value "World!"

echo $dynset->hello . $dynset->world; // outputs "Hello World!"
```

Try extending the "DynamicSettings" class and using those keys as class members now.